# React-Router - Accessing private routes when reloading the application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

First time posting here

I'm having a hard time making private routes accessible directly on the first page load (or under page reload).

What happens is that the private route is based on state, and logically when I reload my page the user object returns null, then it redirects to a public page.

What would do you do when you have to protect routes and keep the route accessible on direct page load?

Thank you for your feedbacks

Comment: I've been able to solve that by changing the condition to access the private route by authenticating directly with the server instead. But it raises a question: isn't it bad to hit the server for authentication on each private page load? because now basically every time I access a private route I have a server request

Comment: What maybe I would do is  that on the page load i would try to get user profile from API and then if it is successful (means it's authenticated) it would proceed him to private route and if not he would be proceeded to public route.

Comment: Otherwise you could for example save user token to localStorage and show private route based on that. if it's persistent then show and if not then redirect to public. But Remember that in this case it could be also nice if you are checking token expiration etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The first possibility is what I'm doing right now. I forgot to mention I have two user types and distinct routes. What I want to avoid is users to change the user type in state manually and accessing the routes